# Set flow access for Guest User Profile in Experience site when installing with a managed package

Tags: visual-workflow, managed-package, digital-experience

Is it possible to set flow access for Guest User Profile in Experience site when installing with a managed package? I followed the article below and set the flow access for the Guest User Profile but they still don't have access.   As stated in the article the Run Flows permission is removed from new orgs starting in Winter ’21 for the Guest User and Experience Cloud External User profiles.  The flow in a managed package does not have the 'Edit Access' option in the dropdown in Setup/Flows.    Thanks                     https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_security.htm&type=5

Comment: Can you check 'API Version for Running the Flow' is 55 or above ?

Comment: It is 55.  I actually got it to work in a second scratch org. There may be a namespace issue causing some strangeness. I created the 2nd scratch org with the same namespace as the package. Not finding a lot of good documentation on developing 2gp with a namespace so groping my way through. Still testing some things but I think it may have been related to a namespace issue..